# How to setup the netCDF4 package in multistage docker build?

Tags: python, docker, netcdf, netcdf4

I have an existing dockerfile that runs a python program involving netCDF4. Here's a simplified version:

```
ARG BASE_IMG=python:3.11-slim
ARG VENV="/opt/venv"

# ------------------------------ #
FROM $BASE_IMG
ARG VENV

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y python3-dev libhdf5-dev libnetcdf-dev

RUN python -m venv $VENV
ENV PATH="$VENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN pip install numpy~=1.23.5 netcdf4~=1.6.4 h5py~=3.9.0

COPY test.py test.py

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "test"]
```

My full dockerfile involves some c++ compilation as well, and I want to covert this into a multistage build so the compilation tools don't end up in my final image. While I'm at it, I figured I could also `pip install` my python packages in the compile stage as well, and move the whole venv over to the final stage like so:

```
ARG BASE_IMG=python:3.11-slim
ARG VENV="/opt/venv"

FROM $BASE_IMG as compile-image
ARG VENV

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y python3-dev libhdf5-dev libnetcdf-dev

RUN python -m venv $VENV
ENV PATH="$VENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN pip install numpy~=1.23.5 netcdf4~=1.6.4 h5py~=3.9.0

# ------------------------------ #
FROM $BASE_IMG
ARG VENV

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev libnetcdf-dev

COPY --from=compile-image $VENV $VENV
ENV PATH="$VENV/bin:$PATH"

COPY test.py test.py

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "test"]
```

This works great, *except* copying the netCDF4 package over this way seems to result in a large slow down in netcdf read/write operations. I can make an identical Dockerfile to the one above where I just install netCDF4 directly in the final stage, and I *don't* see this slow down, so I'm thinking there is some sort of external c lib the netCDF4 package is using that I also need to copy over. Does anyone know how to determine whether netCDF4 has linked to all its libs correctly, or what I need to copy over specifically to make this work?

Comment: I would suggest using https://github.com/wagoodman/dive and https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-diff to compare the two images.

Answer (score 1):

Using [test_echam_spectral-deflated.nc](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/test_echam_spectral-deflated.nc) as a test file. Not sure what you are doing with the data, but my test script loads all variables from the `.nc` file:

`test.py`

```
import time
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

netcdf_file_path = '/data/test_echam_spectral-deflated.nc'

start_time = time.time()

dataset = Dataset(netcdf_file_path, mode='r')

for var in dataset.variables:
    np.array(dataset.variables[var][:])

end_time = time.time()

elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"Time taken to load the NetCDF file: {elapsed_time} seconds")

dataset.close()
```

The data are shared with a container via a volume mount.

I don't see a significant difference in load times. Here's your first `Dockerfile`:

[image]

And this is the second, multistage `Dockerfile`.

[image]

Can you please provide more information which can be used to replicate the issue?